# Difference between CSS and DOM notation in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, performance, dom

I'm wondering if there is a significant difference between using CSS vs. DOM notation when manipulating objects in jQuery.

Say I want to change an object's background position, I could either use:

```
$(this).css({
  'background-position' : xPos + 'px ' + yPos + 'px'
  //         ^
});
```

or:

```
$(this).css({
  'backgroundPosition' : xPos + 'px ' + yPos + 'px'
  //         ^
});
```

I understand that the first is CSS notation and the second is DOM notation. The question here is: when does this matter? Are there any noticeable differences in terms of browser performance or other considerations that need to be taken into account?

Comment: It really doesn't matter.  No, there are no considerations that need to be taken into account, other than code readability.

Comment: "I understand that the first is CSS notation and the second is DOM notation" no, that's not correct at all. Those are just different ways of specifying object properties in JavaScript.

Comment: oh wait, now that i read it again, i realize that you're talking about the hyphenated version, rather than the presence (or lack) of quotes. I'll just go put my foot in my mouth.

Comment: I can imagine that the second manipulates a document object property directly, while the first needs to be parsed by the browser's CSS parser, so based on that assumption, the second one might be faster. But there might by other JQuery magic that turns this reasoning completely upside down. Anyway, the difference, if it is there at all, will probably be so incredibly small that you would have to execute both lines a great number of times to measure the difference. If speed is that important to you, you wouldn't use JQuery for this. Long story short: don't bother. :)

Comment: @zzzzBov Hm, alright, but that's how the jQuery API doc explains them: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: @zzzzBov Just got your second comment. All good.

Comment: the reason for the quotes around the 'CSS' version is because you cannot access properties names that contain a - or a space for that matter without them. there is no performance hit worthy of consideration here, use which ever you prefer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery automatically camel cases hyphenated CSS properties. It's probably slightly more efficient to just use the camel cased version, but you shouldn't even care because it's probably not a performance bottleneck.

You should use whichever version makes your code easier to read and understand.

Comment: Alright, I'll stick to my familiar CSS notation if the difference is so negligible.  Thanks for your help!